# PHP - how to access this data structure?

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

This is a newbie question - how do I access the value0, value1, ... entities?

```
         object(SimpleXMLElement)#43 (2) {
            ["@attributes"]=>
            array(3) {
              ["ABC"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["DEF"]=>
              string(14) "recordXYZ"
              ["GHI"]=>
              string(1) "@"
            }
            ["qwerty"]=>
            array(5) {
              [0]=>
              string(4) "value0"
              [1]=>
              string(1) "value1"
              [2]=>
              string(2) "value2"
              [3]=>
              string(2) "value3"
              [4]=>
              string(4) "value4"
            }
          }
```

Comment: Ahh! Thanks folks! Just spaZZed out for a min there! Everyone's right, of course... thanks Gumbo, Yada and Michiel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just plain array access

```
$value0 = $object->qwerty[0]
$value1 = $object->qwerty[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

When `$object` is the [SimpleXMLElement object](http://php.net/simplexmlelement) you showed, then `$object->qwerty` is the array with your values.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($object->querty as $val) {
    var_dump($val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [children()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) function in the [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/SimpleXMLElement) documentation for an example.